# jCarousel plugin - when set to auto it halts after each advance

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the jCarousel plugin from http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

I have the carousel automatically scrolling through the images. I want to drop the little pause before each scroll animation - can anybody give me an idea where or how to get rid of that in the plugin

ALTERNATIVELY

Is there maybe a better plugin to do a continuing flow of images like a carousel across a page - I am trying to fix the 'halt' issue on this page

http://interiorobjects.com.dnnmax.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `auto` to `0.001` which still pauses, but only one millisecond before continuing. (So basically, no pause)  Their code multiplies `1000 x options.auto` to arrive at the amount to delay. Setting auto to `0` cancels the auto feature.

However, you could use [AnythingSlider](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/) with the following options:

```
$("selector").anythingSlider({
   delay: 0, 
   animationTime: 4000,
   buildNavigation: false,
   pauseOnHover: false
});
```

Since it is meant to be navigated normally, it adds forward/backward buttons as well as a Start/Stop button. You can either edit the plugin, or just hide those elements with CSS:

```
selector a.arrow, selector #start-stop { display: none }
```

In these examples, `selector` refers to the CSS selector needed for jQuery or CSS to properly identify your `div`. Since you are using `.NET` I would recommend using a class vs. trying to output the ID from .NET into your selector and CSS.

Comment: Okay - first - the 0.001 on the old jCarousel plugin doesnt do what you would think

Second the Anything slider wont show like the example i posted - sorry no go

Comment: @codemypantsoff. I stand corrected. Not sure what I was thinking with AnythingSlider. It originally had the ability to show more than one pane at a time, and I removed it. As far as the `0.001`, you also need to set `easing` to 'linear' and a few other settings. I hacked this together to demonstrate, though I didn't go as far as to enable the circular wrap: http://pixelgraphics.s3.amazonaws.com/stackoverflow/jcarousel/examples/static_auto.html

Comment: It still pauses ever so briefly, so it may not be what you need in the end.

Comment: Nope that exactly what i was looking for i didnt realize the easing needed a specific setting -

Comment: Oh good! It partially makes up for the AnythingSlider suggestion :)